# Need explanation regarding 'sort' function behavior in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

**UPDATE** - Thanks @baoo for referring me to a similar question.
I guess I should search more extensively on SO for similar questions, before making one of my own.

I am trying to sort an array using the '**sort**' function in JS as follows :-

```
var arr = [4, 3, 2, 1, 10];
console.log(arr.sort());
```

However, instead of the **expected output** as [**1, 2, 3, 4, 10**], the **actual output** obtained is **[1, 10, 2, 3, 4]**.

Upon searching on the Web, I found that the values are getting sorted as **string**.

However, the type of the elements is indeed a '**number**', as could be verified with the following code :-

```
typeof(arr[0]) // outputs 'number'
```

Further, with the following code the expected output of **[1, 2, 3, 4, 10]** is indeed obtained :-

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; })
```

Could someone please throw some light on what exactly is happening here ?

Thanks.

Comment: The values are coerced to a string if they aren't already before comparison.

Comment: The default comparison function is `function (a,b) { return String(a).localeCompare(b); }`

Comment: @4castle, Thanks for the explanation..:)